# 502 Bad Gateway Error on Google Cloud with PostgreSQL and Node Managed Database

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, database-performance, http-status-code-502

I'm encountering intermittent 502 Bad Gateway errors on my server, which is running a Node.js application connected to a Google Cloud managed PostgreSQL database. The errors seem to occur sporadically, lasting from a few seconds to a few minutes. I've observed that the issue surfaced after a spike in requests, but we've experienced larger spikes without encountering this problem in the past.

Here are some details about the setup:

I'm using Google Cloud for hosting my PostgreSQL database and Node.js application.
The server runs smoothly under normal load, and there are no issues during lower traffic periods.
The 502 errors occur intermittently, and I'm having trouble pinpointing the root cause.

**Additional Details:**

**Traffic Spike:** This issue seemed to coincide with a spike in requests from 2.6k to 7.5k. However, similar or larger spikes in the past did not trigger the 502 errors.

**Resource Utilization:** I've monitored resource utilization on both the database and the Node.js server during the errors, and there are no significant spikes in CPU, memory, or disk usage.

**Logs:** I've checked the logs on both the application and the database, but there are no apparent errors or warnings related to the 502 errors.

**Questions:**

What could be causing these intermittent 502 errors, especially considering that the server has handled larger spikes in traffic without issue in the past?

Are there specific logs or diagnostic tools within Google Cloud that I should be checking to get more insights into the root cause?

Are there any common pitfalls or misconfigurations related to Google Cloud managed PostgreSQL and Node.js that might lead to such intermittent 502 errors?

Any guidance or suggestions on troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your post does not include details on your system configuration. How are requests being routed or proxied to Node.js? ***502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server.***

Comment: Hi, Would you please describe your configuration in more detail: 
Does your application use the Cloud SQL SQL NodeJS Connector? Are you using IAM Authentication or traditional database password auth? Are you using the database's public or private IP address?